Instagram Graph Api Qouta Check
I am using Instagram Graph API following these steps.

I am adding an test account.
Then I get token for this test account.
I make api calls with this token.

I get responses and it works fine. But I cant find my request counts or how many request limit i have.
I check this link for Instagram Graph API
But I dont see any of these contents in my  response's header part. Here is an example from my response.

x-app-usage: {"call_volume":0,"cpu_time":0}

